# Problem converting a HTML file containing Dynamic data to PHP Base64 format on a Laravel API

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, base64

Am working on a Laravel API application whereby I have some dynamic data. I am looping through the data (which is an array) inside the html. The html is embedded in a PHP variable using herodoc format.

After populating the dynamic variables in the html , am storing the content in a variable and convert it to base64 format and return as a response.

The problem is the PHP variables inside the HTML arent being iterated correctly and are throwing errors: **ErrorException
Array to string conversion**

**My PHP Function**

```
public function showPDF($data){

        $names = $data[0];
        $amount = $data[1];


        //Embedded HTMl whereby am populating the above variables
        $my_var = <<<EOD
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html> 
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

            <title> PDF Output| </title>

            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    font-size: 13px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Benefits</th>
                    <th> Benefit Limit</th>
                    <th> Cover</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach($names as $name){ ?>
                        <td> <?php echo $name ?> </td>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <td> 14-05-2019 </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        </body>
        </html>
        EOD;

        dd($my_var);

        //Convert Final PDF to base64
        $b64Doc = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($my_var)));

        return $b64Doc;
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into Laravel's templating called blade https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade. Also you cannot execute a loop inside of a Heredoc.

Comment: @Marinus I have tried using blade templating file,, but since am using POSTMAN for creating the API I get a blank response,, I need to view the layout,,

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a linked list you can`t call it as array first check which data type is in

```
names = data[0]
```